# How can I use git from within Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4

How can I use git from within Xcode? I've found SVN easy to use from Xcode; can I use git as easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XCode 4 you get git support natively.
There's a buch of documentations on the internet:

- https://github.com/blog/810-xcode-4-released-with-git-integration
- http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/on-git-support-in-xcode-4/

Official doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215).

Also, Google has LOADS of results on this matter...

Answer (score 3):

You CAN use git easily from Xcode. Easily, but not *well*.

One of the design decisions Apple made with Xcode was to present a unified interface to version management regardless of what version control system was on the back-end. So if you're using git, you only get the subset of git functionality that svn also supports. No index, no stash, not really even branching.

I've quit trying to use Xcode's onboard git "integration". It's broken by design.

Comment: So are you managing the code files from an external application or from the cmd line?

Comment: I do my git work on the command line. It's my preferred environment for most things anyway, so it's fairly natural for me. There are several stand-alone GUI git applications that do fine. I like Tower very much--it's powerful and beautiful (but not free).